# How many $1$'s could there be in this sequence? Matrix, operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, operator-theory

For each $(i,j)\in \mathbb{N}^2$, $a(i,j)=1$ or $0$, and 1) $a(i,i)=0$ for all $i$; 2)for fixed $i$, there is at most one $j$ such that $a(i,j)=1$. Suppose we know that there is a finite $\kappa$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i\in S, j\in S^{C}}a(i,j)\le\kappa\end{equation}
for any subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$,then one can show $\sum a(i,j)$ is bounded by $3\kappa$.

I am asking what is the largest possible value of $\sum a(i,j)$.

For people who are interested in the background, I am considering an operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(\ell^2)$. With respect to the natural basis, the entries of $T$ are $a(i,j)$. The existence of $\kappa$ in the first inequality is the same as 
\begin{equation}rank(TP-PTP)\le\kappa\end{equation} for all orthogonal projections $P$ in the masa (maximal abelian, self-adjoint subalgebra) of diagonal operators.

In a recent paper by Popov, Marcoux and Radjavi ([Almost Invariant Halfspaces and Approximate Commutation](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4621)), they have shown $\sum a(i,j)$ is bounded by $3\kappa$ (Thm 4.7), but in almost all examples I can think of, $\sum a(i,j)\le 2\kappa$, so I wonder whether the coefficient can be improved.

Again, I think the problem has been reduced to a purely algebraic or number theoretic problem in the first two paragraph of this post.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i\neq j} a(i,j)$?  Else why couldn't $a(i,i)=1$ for all $i$?

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks! I have corrected my post by imposing $a(i,i)=0$ for all $i$. This corresponds to a trivial case in the original problem.

Comment: Citation for the Popov et al. paper?

Comment: When you write, "in *almost* all the examples I can think of...," can you give an example where $2k$ doesn't work?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I mean all the example I can think of.  I tried some finite dimensional matrices they all obey the $\le 2\kappa$ rule. I added a link to the paper.

Comment: I feel that [this paper](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/scott/Papers/acyclic.pdf) of Alon et al must have considerable bearing on the problem, but I can't seem to reconcile the first sentence of the abstract with the $3 \kappa$ result.  Unless I'm missing something, they seem to be in contradiction.

Comment: @ErickWong Sorry I do not know much about graph theory and combinatorics. Could you explain a little bit what is the main idea and results of Alon's paper and why you think there is a contradiction?

Comment: @HuiYu: Let's make sure I understand the question correctly: doesn't $a(1,2)=a(2,3)=a(3,1)=1$ achieve $\sum a(i,j) = 3\kappa$ for $\kappa=1$?

Comment: Cross post on MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100417/how-many-1s-could-be-there-in-this-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a small counterexample with $\kappa=3$:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&0&1\\
1&1&0&0&0
\end{array}
\right).$$
More generally, it is easy to prove an upper bound of $4 \kappa$, and I am inclined to believe it is asymptotically best possible (I guess the Alon paper cites a bound of the form $4 \kappa - O(\sqrt{\kappa}))$.

For the modified problem, where each row can have at most one 1, the stated upper bound $3\kappa$, assuming it is now accurate, is achieved by taking multiple disjoint copies of $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
\end{array}
\right)$.  This satisfies the constraint using $\kappa$ copies for a total of $3\kappa$.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I was thinking about the original problem in the paper and forgot some other cases. I now realize that my problem here is not equivalent to the one I was thinking. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I changed the problem a little bit. I made "for each $i$, there is at most one $j$ such that $a(i,j)=1$" a restriction on the matrix. I think know the problem is equivalent to the problem in the paper. So we have $3\kappa$ as an upper bound. I wonder whether this can be improved. Thanks!

Comment: @HuiYu I still don't see how this additional condition changes the $3 \times 3$ example I posted in the comments above.

Comment: That still works. But in that case we have $\sum a(i,j)\le 2\kappa+1$, so maybe the bound is $2\kappa+1$. Asymptotically it might be $2\kappa+const$.

Comment: @HuiYu In the $6\times 6$ version formed from two copies of the $3\times 3$ example, I get $\kappa = 2$ with the matrix adding up to $6$.  How do you arrive at $2\kappa+1$?